# Returning a text attribute with the earliest and latest date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question as follows for excel.  I would like to return a text attribute with the earliest date per group in excel.  Would there be a simple way to do this using a formula? An Example is below of the desired output -  I am looking to create "Earliest Type per client" & "Latest Type per client" and have these repeat per client.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following array formula to `E2` cell

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,ROW($B$2:$B$7)-ROW($A$1),"")))
```

Use following array formula to `F2` cell

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,ROW($B$2:$B$7)-ROW($A$1),"")))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

If you wish non array formula then can go with following for excel 2010 and later.

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$7)/(($A$1:$A$7=A2)*($B$1:$B$7>=MIN($B$1:$B$7))),1))
```

Comment: Thank You.  The array is fine.  Regards  ML.

Comment: glad it helps you.